# I'm stuck at implementing some if,elif and else statments

Tags: python, if-statement, digits

I'm trying to finish an assignment but everything I have tried so far has failed.

```
def valid_format(s):
    
  pass
    
  z = introcs.count_str(s,',')
  x = introcs.split(s,',')
  y = introcs.find_str(s,',')

  if len(s) >= 2:
      if s[0] == '0':
            return False
                    
  if len(s) <= 3:
      if introcs.isdigit(s):
          x = int(s)
          if x >= -1 and x <= 999:
              if z == 0:
                  return True
          else:
              return False
      else:
          return False
    
  if len(s) >= 4 and len(s)<= 7:
      if introcs.isdigit(s):
          x = int(s)
          if x >= 999 and x <= 1000000:
              return True
          else:
              return False
      else:
          return False
```

It looks like I'm not very good with if's statements since every time I try something new, it ends up giving me the same result. The code works(?) until I try numbers with comma (1,230 for example). Any tips and explanations of what I'm doing wrong  or what I should change will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Sorry for not providing enough details. The function needs to return True if s is a valid numerical string and it has to be less than 7 characters. I'm having difficulty with the commas. I get the opposite answer(either True or False)

For example:
I get True when It should be False

```
valid_format('2389')
True
```

But False when it should be True

```
valid_format('2,389')
False
```

I need this type of result:

```
valid_format('2,389')
True

valid_format('32,45')
False
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what the difference is between what you expect to happen and what actually happens with a few examples?

Comment: "The code works(?) until I try numbers with comma (1,230 for example)." If the input is `1,230`, what should the result be? What is the actual result? Now, what happens if you try to [follow the logic of the code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? When you supply this input, where does the code start doing things differently from how you intended it to work?

Comment: Why does the function begin with `pass`? That's only needed as a placeholder when you have a block statement with an empty body.

Comment: @Barmar presumably because the student was given a minimally-syntactically-valid template to fill in, and didn't remove the `pass`.

Comment: This is probably not the cause of your problems, but your variable naming is disadvantageous. If you have a variable named `x` and then re-assign that one for a different purpose in certain if clauses, this can lead to unexpected issues.

Comment: You never use the 3 variables `x`, `y`, and `z` that you assign at the beginning.

Comment: You don't need to check if `x <= 999`. If it's at most 3 digits and only digits, it can't be larger.

Comment: @Barmar Well, `z` is used once, but you seem to be right otherwise...

Comment: The code will not run `NameError: name 'introcs' is not defined`. This is not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is what is needed so a runnable answer can be produced with explanations on the solution.

Comment: You can do `s.split(',')` and check that all parts except the first are 3 digits.

Comment: @Carl_M I guess that's a library of utilities provided by their course, analogous to cs50. Although it seems like some of them duplicate Python built-ins. We have to wonder how `introcs.isdigit()` differens from the built-in `str.isdigit()`. The built-in function doesn't allow `-` or `,`, so we wouldn't need to check for those conditions in that `if` block.

Comment: So, there are three parts.  If len(x) > 7, fail.  If len(x) > 1 and x[0] == '0',. fail.  Then, split on the commas.  Check that each part passes `isdigit` and is exactly 3 digits long, except that the first must be 3 or less.  That's really all there is.

Comment: Add print statements, so you can find out which code branches it took, for each input. Then it will be easy for you to see under what conditions it took the wrong branch. Then add more print statements, until you find *exactly* what caused it to take that wrong branch. If you still can't solve it, you'll be able to ask a precise question, such as "when input is ..., why does ... happen on line of code ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0
for i in range(len(s)-1,-1,-1):
    count+=1
    if count%4==0:  #make sure every 4th char is a ','
        if s[i]==',':
            pass
        else:
            return False
    else:
        if ord(s[i])-ord('0')<0 or ord(s[i])-ord('0')>9: #check if char is valid 0-9 using ascii arithmetic 
            return False
        else:
            pass
    if i==0:
        if ord(s[i])-ord('0')>9 or ord(s[i])-ord('0')<1: #check first digit is valid 1-9
            return False
return True
```